# Adding and removing from array

Tags: java

I'm trying to test my Club methods through my Main class, however I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to add/remove to my class. I believe it might have something to do with my default constructor in my Member class?

Apologies as I'm still a beginner

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Member defaultMember = new Member();
    Member member = new Member("John","Smith", 2, 1990);
    Club club = new Club();


}
```

}

public class Club {

```
private Member[] members;


public Club() {

    members = new Member[5];
}

public void join(Member member) {
    for(int i=0; i<members.length; i++) {
        if(members[i] == null) {
            members[i] = new Member();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No room");
        }
    }
}

public int numberOfMembers() {
    return members.length;
}

public void showMembers() {
    for(int i=0; i<members.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(members[i]);
    }
}

public void showMembersByYear(int year) {
    for(int i=0; i<members.length; i++) {
        if(year == members[i].getJoinYear()) {
            System.out.println(members[i]);
        }
    }
}

public void removeMembersByYear(int year) {
    for(int i=0; i<members.length; i++) {
        if(year == members[i].getJoinYear()) {

        }
    }
}
```

}

public class Member {

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int joinMonth;
private int joinYear;

public static final int FIRST_MONTH = 1;
public static final int LAST_MONTH = 12;
public static final int CURRENT_YEAR = 2018;
public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "unknown";

public Member() {

}

public Member(String firstName, String lastName, int joinMonth, int joinYear) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setJoinMonth(joinMonth);
    setJoinYear(joinYear);
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    if(firstName != null) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    } else {
        this.firstName = DEFAULT_NAME;
    }
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    if(lastName != null) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    } else {
        this.lastName = DEFAULT_NAME;
    }
}

public void setJoinMonth(int joinMonth) {
    if(joinMonth >= FIRST_MONTH && joinMonth <= LAST_MONTH) {
        this.joinMonth = joinMonth;
    } else {
        this.joinMonth = FIRST_MONTH;
    }
}

public void setJoinYear(int joinYear) {
    if(joinYear >= 0 && joinYear <= CURRENT_YEAR) {
        this.joinYear = joinYear;
    } else {
        this.joinYear = CURRENT_YEAR;
    }
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public int getJoinMonth() {
    return joinMonth;
}

public int getJoinYear() {
    return joinYear;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you required to use Array, and not allowed to use ArrayList or other collection?

Comment: `members = new Member[5];` will allow you to have only 5 members in the club if you don't want to reassign `members` with a larger or smaller array every time you add or remove a member. Removal of a member will leave an empty index in that array. Consider using a `Collection`, like a `List<Member>` or maybe a `Set<Member>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code.

```
 if(members[i] == null) {
      members[i] = new Member();
  }
```

here you are assigning a new member object to your array and not the one you sent as a parameter.

change it to `member[i] = member;`

and there is a logical problem in your join function initially all elements of the array will be null so the loop will assign member object to all available spaces on the first call afterwards you will get no room.

And your numberOfMembers() function also has a logical problem it will always print 5 as it is the size you gave while making a members array.

Also, your showMembers function will print references to the objects and not the information stored in them.

You can read about printing objects here: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/print-object

**EDIT - FOR JOIN LOGICAL PROBLEM**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Member defaultMember = new Member();
    Member member = new Member("John","Smith", 2, 1990);
    Club club = new Club();
    club.join(member);
    club.showMembers();

}
```

above main function will print(considering your showMembers() works correctly)

```
John Smith 2 1990
John Smith 2 1990
John Smith 2 1990
John Smith 2 1990
John Smith 2 1990
```

the reason is that you have assigned the same member to all available spaces. And now if you try to do

```
Member secondMember = new Member("ali","tahir","2","1990")
club.join(secondMember)
```

you will get `no room`"

hence, your method of adding a new member to the club is logically wrong

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

"and there is a logical problem in your join function initially all elements of the array will be null so the loop will assign member object to all available spaces on the first call afterwards you will get no room."

I understand that arrays are assigned null values by default, but what do you mean by "the first call afterwards you will get no room"

Comment: I have added some elaboration to the problem in the edit.

Comment: I see what you mean. The for loop is adding my first object and filling up the array with the same object. I can't figure out how to isolate the specific array index to each new member object

Comment: if you are self-learning you need guidence and it seems like you need to practice array problems try hacker rank or leet code. if you are not restricted in using a simple array think about using  other data structures that can also help with time complexity. You can also read "Teach Yourself Java in 21 days" for better understanding. And if you are still struggling ask another question with the solutions you have tried so far.